# SetEmptyText() dosen't show up when ListFragment is Empty

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I'm working with ListFragments .. I want to use setEmptyText() when the list is empty but it doesn't show it keep displaying a progress it keeps displaying a progress bar I don't know exactly where the layout that contains this list and here's my code

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    new getData().execute();
}

private class getData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Object>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Object> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            artists = new ArrayList<Object>();
            artists = loadArtists("taqwa.xml");
            return loadXml("taqwa.xml");
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Utils.log("XML exception", "true");
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Utils.log("IOException", "true");

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Object> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result != null) {
            ListAdapter ladapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(),
                    R.layout.list_row, null, artists, 3);
            setListAdapter(ladapter);
        } else {
            setEmptyText("not found wallahi!");
        }

    }

}
```

as you can see I don't use layout that contains like @id/android:list to add @id/android:empty .. I only send the the list item to a baseAdapter

Comment: Can you post what is inside setEmptyText() method? And also whenever you make any changes to adapter call notifyDatasetChanged() method.

Comment: I didn't override the setEmptyText() method

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you don't have an adapter for list view, so setEmptyText() doesn't work.

Comment: Good tip. This isn't documented anywhere, but it appears that before the adapter is set, only the indeterminate progress widget is shown in the default layout.